# Acausality in Scalar Field Theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, field-theory, causality

In the *"[Lectures on Physics Beyond the Standard Model](https://inspirehep.net/literature/1684708)"* (Matthew McCullough, CERN), it is said that in following lagrangian density we have acausality because of the negative sign in the second term.

\begin{align}
\ell = \frac{1}{2}\partial_{\mu}\phi\partial^{\mu}\phi - \frac{1}{\Lambda^{4}}(\partial_{\mu}\phi\partial^{\mu}\phi)^{2} 
\end{align}

I find the equation of motion for the scalar field as follows:
\begin{align}
\Box\phi - \frac{12}{\Lambda^{4}}\Box\phi \partial_{\mu}\phi\partial^{\mu}\phi=0 
\end{align}

but I can not understand how to see acausality in it.

Comment: Do you know how to draw a Feynman diagram for a Lagrangian involving a term such as $(\partial \phi \partial \phi)^2$? Or, can you calculate the commutator of the fields at spacelike separated points for the given Lagrangian?

Comment: @DvijD.C. Thanks for your attention,But The Problem is I can not solve equation of motion of scalar field and find operator form of it to calculate commutators.

Comment: You need to read that famous paper by Arkani-Hamed et al. cited there. They showed that wrong signs lead to fluctuations which have superluminal propagation, that is, they propagate with a speed $>c$. This is acausality.

Comment: @Avantgarde Thanks, your guidance is the answer which I look For.